# SVG in React Component

Tags: reactjs, svg, material-ui, react-functional-component

i've downloaded an svg image which i was intending in using it as a react component  , but i paste the svg code to the functional component i get error markes within the  tags , what i can do to fix this so ill be able to use the icon

```
import React from 'react'

const CardanoIcon = () => {
  return (
    <svg height="256" viewBox="0 0 256 256" width="256" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><defs><style>
      .cls-1 {
        fill: #3468d1;
      }

      .cls-2 {
        fill: #fff;
        fill-rule: evenodd;
      }
    </style></defs><g data-name="cardano ada" id="cardano_ada"><g data-name="cardano ada" id="cardano_ada-2"><circle class="cls-1" cx="128" cy="128" data-name="Эллипс 6" id="Эллипс_6" r="128"/><path class="cls-2" d="M265.727,717.735a12.652,12.652,0,1,1-12.654,12.652A12.654,12.654,0,0,1,265.727,717.735Zm30.546,0a12.652,12.652,0,1,1-12.655,12.652A12.654,12.654,0,0,1,296.273,717.735Zm0,53.226a12.652,12.652,0,1,1-12.655,12.652A12.653,12.653,0,0,1,296.273,770.961Zm-30.546,0a12.652,12.652,0,1,1-12.654,12.652A12.653,12.653,0,0,1,265.727,770.961Zm-15.709-26.177a12.652,12.652,0,1,1-12.654,12.652A12.654,12.654,0,0,1,250.018,744.784Zm61.964,0a12.652,12.652,0,1,1-12.655,12.652A12.653,12.653,0,0,1,311.982,744.784Zm14.4-21.813a7.853,7.853,0,1,1-7.855,7.853A7.853,7.853,0,0,1,326.382,722.971Zm0,52.352a7.853,7.853,0,1,1-7.855,7.853A7.853,7.853,0,0,1,326.382,775.323Zm-90.764,0a7.853,7.853,0,1,1-7.854,7.853A7.854,7.854,0,0,1,235.618,775.323Zm0-52.352a7.853,7.853,0,1,1-7.854,7.853A7.854,7.854,0,0,1,235.618,722.971ZM281,696.794a7.853,7.853,0,1,1-7.855,7.853A7.853,7.853,0,0,1,281,696.794ZM281,801.5a7.853,7.853,0,1,1-7.855,7.853A7.853,7.853,0,0,1,281,801.5Zm33.6,7.853a6.544,6.544,0,1,1-6.546,6.544A6.544,6.544,0,0,1,314.6,809.353Zm-67.2,0a6.544,6.544,0,1,1-6.546,6.544A6.544,6.544,0,0,1,247.4,809.353Zm0-117.794a6.544,6.544,0,1,1-6.546,6.544A6.544,6.544,0,0,1,247.4,691.559Zm67.2,0a6.544,6.544,0,1,1-6.546,6.544A6.544,6.544,0,0,1,314.6,691.559Zm34.036,58.461a6.544,6.544,0,1,1-6.545,6.544A6.545,6.545,0,0,1,348.636,750.02Zm-135.273,0a6.544,6.544,0,1,1-6.545,6.544A6.544,6.544,0,0,1,213.363,750.02Zm-4.8-40.138a5.236,5.236,0,1,1-5.236,5.235A5.236,5.236,0,0,1,208.563,709.882Zm0,83.765a5.236,5.236,0,1,1-5.236,5.235A5.236,5.236,0,0,1,208.563,793.647Zm144.873,0a5.236,5.236,0,1,1-5.236,5.235A5.236,5.236,0,0,1,353.436,793.647Zm0-83.765a5.236,5.236,0,1,1-5.236,5.235A5.236,5.236,0,0,1,353.436,709.882ZM281,668a5.236,5.236,0,1,1-5.237,5.235A5.235,5.235,0,0,1,281,668Zm0,167.529a5.236,5.236,0,1,1-5.237,5.236A5.236,5.236,0,0,1,281,835.529Zm46.254-3.49a4.363,4.363,0,1,1-4.363,4.363A4.363,4.363,0,0,1,327.254,832.039Zm-92.509,0a4.363,4.363,0,1,1-4.363,4.363A4.363,4.363,0,0,1,234.745,832.039Zm0-158.8a4.363,4.363,0,1,1-4.363,4.363A4.363,4.363,0,0,1,234.745,673.235Zm92.509,0a4.363,4.363,0,1,1-4.363,4.363A4.363,4.363,0,0,1,327.254,673.235Zm45.382,79.4A4.363,4.363,0,1,1,368.273,757,4.363,4.363,0,0,1,372.636,752.637Zm-183.273,0A4.363,4.363,0,1,1,185,757,4.363,4.363,0,0,1,189.363,752.637Z" data-name="Эллипс 6 копия 29" id="Эллипс_6_копия_29" transform="translate(-152 -629)"/></g></g></svg>
  )
}

export default CardanoIcon
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a file like an icon.svg and paste the SVG you have downloaded to that file then you can import SVG file in your component like this:

```
import icon from './icon.svg'
const CustomIcon = () => {
  return (
      <img src={icon} alt="icon" />
    )
 }
 export default CustomIcon;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [CRA (Create React App)](https://create-react-app.dev/) for your React environment, I would suggest pulling out the contents of the `<style>` tag out into a separate .css file and then importing it into the React component.

So, your `CardanoIcon.css` would look as follows:

```
.cls-1 {
  fill: #3468d1;
}

.cls-2 {
  fill: #fff;
  fill-rule: evenodd;
}
```

And your React component would look as follows - note the .css import on line 2. Also, note that you need to change `class` to `className`

```js
import React from 'react';
import './CardanoIcon.css';

const CardanoIcon = () => (
  <svg
    height="256"
    viewBox="0 0 256 256"
    width="256"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  >
    <defs></defs>
    <g data-name="cardano ada" id="cardano_ada">
      <g data-name="cardano ada" id="cardano_ada-2">
        <circle
          className="cls-1"
          cx="128"
          cy="128"
          data-name="Эллипс 6"
          id="Эллипс_6"
          r="128"
        />
        <path
          className="cls-2"
          d="M265.727,717.735a12.652,12.652,0,1,1-12.654,12.652A12.654,12.654,0,0,1,265.727,717.735Zm30.546,0a12.652,12.652,0,1,1-12.655,12.652A12.654,12.654,0,0,1,296.273,717.735Zm0,53.226a12.652,12.652,0,1,1-12.655,12.652A12.653,12.653,0,0,1,296.273,770.961Zm-30.546,0a12.652,12.652,0,1,1-12.654,12.652A12.653,12.653,0,0,1,265.727,770.961Zm-15.709-26.177a12.652,12.652,0,1,1-12.654,12.652A12.654,12.654,0,0,1,250.018,744.784Zm61.964,0a12.652,12.652,0,1,1-12.655,12.652A12.653,12.653,0,0,1,311.982,744.784Zm14.4-21.813a7.853,7.853,0,1,1-7.855,7.853A7.853,7.853,0,0,1,326.382,722.971Zm0,52.352a7.853,7.853,0,1,1-7.855,7.853A7.853,7.853,0,0,1,326.382,775.323Zm-90.764,0a7.853,7.853,0,1,1-7.854,7.853A7.854,7.854,0,0,1,235.618,775.323Zm0-52.352a7.853,7.853,0,1,1-7.854,7.853A7.854,7.854,0,0,1,235.618,722.971ZM281,696.794a7.853,7.853,0,1,1-7.855,7.853A7.853,7.853,0,0,1,281,696.794ZM281,801.5a7.853,7.853,0,1,1-7.855,7.853A7.853,7.853,0,0,1,281,801.5Zm33.6,7.853a6.544,6.544,0,1,1-6.546,6.544A6.544,6.544,0,0,1,314.6,809.353Zm-67.2,0a6.544,6.544,0,1,1-6.546,6.544A6.544,6.544,0,0,1,247.4,809.353Zm0-117.794a6.544,6.544,0,1,1-6.546,6.544A6.544,6.544,0,0,1,247.4,691.559Zm67.2,0a6.544,6.544,0,1,1-6.546,6.544A6.544,6.544,0,0,1,314.6,691.559Zm34.036,58.461a6.544,6.544,0,1,1-6.545,6.544A6.545,6.545,0,0,1,348.636,750.02Zm-135.273,0a6.544,6.544,0,1,1-6.545,6.544A6.544,6.544,0,0,1,213.363,750.02Zm-4.8-40.138a5.236,5.236,0,1,1-5.236,5.235A5.236,5.236,0,0,1,208.563,709.882Zm0,83.765a5.236,5.236,0,1,1-5.236,5.235A5.236,5.236,0,0,1,208.563,793.647Zm144.873,0a5.236,5.236,0,1,1-5.236,5.235A5.236,5.236,0,0,1,353.436,793.647Zm0-83.765a5.236,5.236,0,1,1-5.236,5.235A5.236,5.236,0,0,1,353.436,709.882ZM281,668a5.236,5.236,0,1,1-5.237,5.235A5.235,5.235,0,0,1,281,668Zm0,167.529a5.236,5.236,0,1,1-5.237,5.236A5.236,5.236,0,0,1,281,835.529Zm46.254-3.49a4.363,4.363,0,1,1-4.363,4.363A4.363,4.363,0,0,1,327.254,832.039Zm-92.509,0a4.363,4.363,0,1,1-4.363,4.363A4.363,4.363,0,0,1,234.745,832.039Zm0-158.8a4.363,4.363,0,1,1-4.363,4.363A4.363,4.363,0,0,1,234.745,673.235Zm92.509,0a4.363,4.363,0,1,1-4.363,4.363A4.363,4.363,0,0,1,327.254,673.235Zm45.382,79.4A4.363,4.363,0,1,1,368.273,757,4.363,4.363,0,0,1,372.636,752.637Zm-183.273,0A4.363,4.363,0,1,1,185,757,4.363,4.363,0,0,1,189.363,752.637Z"
          data-name="Эллипс 6 копия 29"
          id="Эллипс_6_копия_29"
          transform="translate(-152 -629)"
        />
      </g>
    </g>
  </svg>
);

export default CardanoIcon;
```